# Browser PDF File Previwer(Google Style)

Tags: java, pdf, browser, preview

I am working on an application which needs to preview privileged content in the browser. The preview should work in a way that its NOT possible to download the content. Only reading within the  browser is allowed. I have looked at google docs preview but it needs the url of the docs to accessible online. I need to work with content in the intranet

The previewer should not mandate the installation of a pluggin as this would limit the access.

Any hints

Comment: How should the browser show the preview if "its NOT possible to download the content." ?? Do you mean that the original pdf should not be downloadable?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). If your're using, say, php, you could do something like

```
exec("convert -resize 500×800 {$file}.pdf {$file}.jpg");
```

and then display the resulting jpg-file on a webpage.

`man convert` should give you some further options.